# RedBeanPHP использовать внутри класса

Tags: php, redbeanphp

По видеогайду делаю структуру MVC и хочу использовать `RedBeanPHP` внутри классов , только вот не знаю как подключить.
Стандартное подключение

```
`require 'rb.php';`
```

Не работает, появляется ошибка

> `Warning: require(app/lib/rb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd2/319/3424319/public_html/app/core/Controller.php on line 28
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'app/lib/rb.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd2/319/3424319/public_html/app/core/Controller.php on line 28`

В общем я хочу использовать статичные методы через класс `R`, и желательно подключить как то через `namespacе`.

Нашел решение. Нужно установить RedBean с помощью Composer.

Comment: У вас в require 'rb.php'; неверно задан путь к файлу rb.php. Сейчас у вас получается что файл rb.php находится в той же папке что и файл Controller.php, а по факту его там нет вот и ошибка. Либо скопируйте rb.php в папку где у вас находится файл Controller.php или задайте в require 'rb.php'; правильный путь к файлу rb.php.

Comment: Да в принципе этот вариант работает. Только вот проблема в том, что я не только в  классе Controller использую методы RedBean, Поэтому приходится этот файл подключать еще  к куче других файлов, что не есть гуд.

Comment: Если у вас файл rb.php находится в `app/lib/`, а Controller.php в `app/core/` то попробуйте в Controller.php подключить так `require '../lib/rb.php';`

Comment: Решить это надо не с помощью подключение файла. Потому что это вообще не то. Если в одном классе подключаешь файл и даже если он наследуется, то файл в другом классе недоступен.
Нужно какое то ООП решение, только вот я не понимаю его пока что.

Comment: Вы используете composer в своем приложении?

Comment: Нет, но кстати я нашел API для composer , других вариантов нет. Пойду разбиратся , что это такое.